# Android studio - don't produce output

Tags: java, android, xml

i want to create an apps that can scan other ip that are connected to my Lan network. this is my java code,maybe there is an error that cause my codding don't produce the result.

```
package com.example.admin.ipscanner3;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView tvWifiState;
TextView tvScanning, tvResult;

ArrayList<InetAddress> inetAddresses;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tvWifiState = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.WifiState);
    tvScanning = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Scanning);
    tvResult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Result);

    //To prevent memory leaks on devices prior to Android N,
    //retrieve WifiManager with
    //getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE),
    //instead of getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE)
    WifiManager wifiManager =
            (WifiManager) 
 getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    tvWifiState.setText(readtvWifiState(wifiManager));

    new ScanTask(tvScanning, tvResult).execute();
    }

    // "android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" is needed
    private String readtvWifiState(WifiManager wm){
    String result = "";
    switch (wm.getWifiState()){
        case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_DISABLED:
            result = "WIFI_STATE_DISABLED";
            break;
        case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_DISABLING:
            result = "WIFI_STATE_DISABLING";
            break;
        case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED:
            result = "WIFI_STATE_ENABLED";
            break;
        case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLING:
            result = "WIFI_STATE_ENABLING";
            break;
        case WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_UNKNOWN:
            result = "WIFI_STATE_UNKNOWN";
            break;
        default:
    }
    return result;
   }

    private class ScanTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {

    TextView tvCurrentScanning, tvScanResullt;
    ArrayList<String> canonicalHostNames;

    public ScanTask(TextView tvCurrentScanning, TextView tvScanResullt) {
        this.tvCurrentScanning = tvCurrentScanning;
        this.tvScanResullt = tvScanResullt;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        tvCurrentScanning.setText("Finished.");
        tvScanResullt.setText("");
        for(int i = 0; i < inetAddresses.size(); i++){
            tvScanResullt.append(canonicalHostNames.get(i) + "\n");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        scanInetAddresses();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
        tvCurrentScanning.setText(values[0]);
    }

    private void scanInetAddresses(){
        //May be you have to adjust the timeout
        final int timeout = 500;

        if(inetAddresses == null){
            inetAddresses = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        inetAddresses.clear();

        if(canonicalHostNames == null){
            canonicalHostNames = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        canonicalHostNames.clear();

        //For demonstration, scan 192.168.1.xxx only
        byte[] ip = {(byte) 183, (byte) 171, (byte) 93, 0};
        for (int j = 0; j < 255; j++) {
            ip[3] = (byte) j;
            try {
                InetAddress checkAddress = InetAddress.getByAddress(ip);
                publishProgress(checkAddress.getCanonicalHostName());
                if (checkAddress.isReachable(timeout)) {
                    inetAddresses.add(checkAddress);

 canonicalHostNames.add(checkAddress.getCanonicalHostName());
                }
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                publishProgress(e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                publishProgress(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

this is my interface/ layout. i think there is no error here.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context="com.example.admin.ipscanner3.MainActivity">

   <TextView
      android:id="@+id/title"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
      android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
      android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
      android:autoLink="web"
      android:text="http://android-er.blogspot.com/"
      android:textStyle="bold"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.069" />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/WifiState"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.144">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Scanning: " />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Scanning"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="italic" />
  </LinearLayout>

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/Result"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.212" />

   </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

i have add this two permission too to get a permission to access the wifi state and the internet.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: First thing Debug method `scanInetAddresses()` make sure the data is fllled without any Exception.

Comment: can you post Logcat error?

Comment: @ShylendraMadda but i don't got any error at logcat